# C# How to access embedded file just like physical file

Tags: c#, dll

I use [MaxentTagger](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html) class of `Stanford Pos Tagger version 3.3.1.1` installed through Nuget Package Manager.

The MaxentTagger class has a constructor that only takes a string as it's argument indicating a file path on local disk. It reads the file and does something. I am not able to modify and recompile MaxentTagger source code.

I have a file called `english.tagger` and wanted to embed it into `dll`. This was fairly simple and it is done.

So, the question is how do i get the embedded `english.tagger` path and pass it to MaxentTagger constructor so that it become able to read the file content just like a local file?

Comment: Sounds like you may have to extract it at runtime to a temporary path (Path.GetTempPath, Path.GetTempFileName) and then pass that path to the constructor. You can't reference an embedded resource with a direct file path. Alternatively, you can access them as Streams. Can your library take a stream as an argument?

Comment: Use a temp file : http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/how-to-use-temporary-files-in-csharp/

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 How do i access it as Stream?

Comment: If the other library wants a file, you have to provide a file.